# url rewrite internal server error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am getting thrown errors every time i implement this code for mod-rewriting in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule   ^commenting/([0-9]+)/?$commenting.php?id=$1
```

I am trying to convert

```
domain/commenting.php?id=15
```

Into something like

```
domain/commenting/15
```

Is it a problem with the code or my hosting. I have not downloaded any plug-ins is that needed?
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

The error is this:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete        your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space between the left and right hand of the rule.

```
RewriteRule ^commenting/([0-9]+)/?$ /commenting.php?id=$1
```

You may as well need to enable the `RewriteEngine` and `Options` resulting on the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^commenting/([0-9]+)/?$ /commenting.php?id=$1
```

If you're still getting 500 after this try placing the above rule between these tags `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>...</IfModule>` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^commenting/([0-9]+)/?$ /commenting.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

The above basically means to execute the rules only if the module that makes it work is available.

Comment: this worked very well! Thank you one more thing though. If you cant tell i am new to this concept. just wondering if you knew why the CSS properties were disabled when I go to this new url

Comment: @user2626282 Let's say you have it like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somecss.css" />` it will try to read the css at `domain/commenting/15/somecss.css` which obviously don't exist. You can use the full path instead for example `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain/somecss.css" />`